# Iterate through characters in a string R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a dataset a bit like this, but with around 50,000 rows:

```
 # some data
 subj <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
 session <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2)
 items <- c("hfg", "hrfg", "thflk", "plht", "sdrpv")

 df <- data.frame(subj, session, items)
```

For each subject (across sessions), I want to compare each character in each row of `df$items` with all the characters in all other rows, using a feature matrix of 11 values, which will be used to calculate Euclidean distance for each value between each character and each other character:

```
 feature_matrix <- tribble(~char, ~val1, ~val2, ~val3, ~val4, ~val5, 
                           ~val6, ~val7, ~val8, ~val9, ~val10, ~val11,
                         "p", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                         "b", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                         "t", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "d", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "k", -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                         "ɡ", -1, 1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 0,
                         "f", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                         "v", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                         "s", -0.5, 1, -1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "c", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 0,   
                         "z", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "h", -0.5, 1, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1,
                         "m", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 0,
                         "n", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "r", 0.5, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1,  
                         "l", 0.5, 0, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 0,
                         "w", 0.8, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 0,
                         "j", 0.8, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1, -1, 0, 1)
```

As an example, to compare "hfg" with "hrfg" for `feature_matrix$val1` only:

```
 h_h1 <- (-0.5--0.5)^2
 h_r1 <- (-0.5-0.5)^2
 h_f1 <- (-0.5--0.5)^2
 h_g1 <- (-0.5--1)^2
 f_h1 <- (-0.5--0.5)^2
 f_r1 <- (-0.5-0.5)^2
```

... and so on, for all 11 values.

These will then be added together, and the square root of each of these 11 values is then added together again to create a final value, the Euclidean distance:

```
 val1_sum <- h_h1 + h_r1 + h_f1 + h_g1 + f_h1 + f_r1...
 val2_sum <- h_h2 + h_r2 + h_f2 + h_g2 + f_h2 + f_r2...
 val3_sum <- .... etc

 distance <- sqrt(val1_sum) + sqrt(val2_sum) + sqrt(val3_sum) + ...
```

This will leave me with a distance matrix.

As a bonus, I'd also like to compare each character in each string with each other character in the same string, though I expect this would need to be done in a separate section of code. Any help gratefully appreciated!

Comment: suppose you have 50.000 items an average of 4 characters for each item. Then you will end with a (symmetric) matrix of 200.000 x 200.000 = 40.000.000.000 items. Is that what you expect?

Comment: @RicVillalba Thank you, I forgot to add this! I've edited the question now so I hope this is clear. It will still be a big matrix, but "only" 50,000 x 50,000.

Comment: @CatherineLaing Just to be clear, that would still take 20 GB of memory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph There are ways that I can subset my data to make it more manageable, so that in itself shouldn't be a major issue.

Comment: Another [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) instance perhaps? In other words, what is the conclusion you intend from you whole work? what do you expect to obtain finally from those huge arrays?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with dplyr / tidyr. However, whether it works will depend on data volume: As it is said in the comments, it quickly become unmanageable as number of comparisions growths.

Some optimizations are feasible, for case, group by character group and count, and even by character group despite the order.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# some data
df <- data.frame(subj = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
  session = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 2),
  items = c("hfg", "hrfg", "thflk", "plht", "sdrpv"))

# features
feature_matrix <- data.frame(char=c("p","b","t","d","k","ɡ","f","v",
"s","c","z","h","m","n","r","l","w","j"),val1=c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,-0.5,0,0,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8),val2=c(1,1,1,1,
1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0),val3=c(-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1),val4=c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,
0,0,0,0),val5=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,-1,-1,0,0),val6=c(1,1,
-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1),val7=c(0,0,1,1,-1,-1,
1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0),val8=c(-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,
-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1),val9=c(1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,
1,-1,1,-1),val10=c(0,0,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,1,-1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,-1,0),
val11=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,0,1))

# decompose items in chars and add column "char"
df_char <- df %>%  mutate(char = strsplit(items, "")) %>% unnest(char) 
head(df_char)

#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>    subj session items char 
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1     1       1 hfg   h    
#> 2     1       1 hfg   f    
#> 3     1       1 hfg   g    
#> 4     1       1 hrfg  h    
#> 5     1       1 hrfg  r    
#> 6     1       1 hrfg  f

# calculate distances
distances <- select(df_char, -items) %>% 
  inner_join(
    select(df_char, -items), 
    by=c("subj"="subj", "session"="session"),
    suffix = c("_l", "_r")) %>% 
    filter(char_l != char_r                          # because distance same char == 0
           & char_l %in% feature_matrix$char         # only chars that are in feature_matrix  
           & char_r %in% feature_matrix$char)  %>%   # (there are missings)
    mutate(
      distance = rowSums((
        slice(feature_matrix, match(char_r, char))[,-1]
        - slice(feature_matrix, match(char_l, char))[,-1]) ^ 2))

distances
#> # A tibble: 68 × 5
#>     subj session char_l char_r distance
#>    <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1     1       1 h      f            15
#>  2     1       1 h      r             9
#>  3     1       1 h      f            15
#>  4     1       1 f      h            15
#>  5     1       1 f      h            15
#>  6     1       1 f      r            18
#>  7     1       1 h      f            15
#>  8     1       1 h      r             9
#>  9     1       1 h      f            15
#> 10     1       1 r      h             9
#> # … with 58 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you, I see that this is what I am looking for but, as you predict, with even a subset of my data this isn't going to work. I have a working script that matches characters from a string based on string position (so char1 in string1 is compared with char1 in string2, but not chars2, 3, 4 etc.), which clearly takes much less memory to compute. Would this be equally problematic using a list to break down the data by `subj` and `session` and then running the computation that way?